# How to add a not found option in the search bar in Tailwind css and Alpine js

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

I am working on a project in tailwindcss and alpine js. I want to make a search bar in it. I have made the search bar but the "Not found" feature is not getting formed. I tried multiple ways still not got the result. Please help me to put a not found feature in my code. Thanks is advance.

Here's my code:

```
<ul class="max-h-72 scroll-py-2 overflow-y-auto text-sm text-gray-800" id="options" role="listbox">
     <template x-for="(item, index) in searchResults">
          <li class="cursor-default select-none px-4 py-2" role="option" x-text="item" tabindex="-1"></li>
     </template>
 </ul>
```

the x-data part of the immediate div is :

```
x-data="{ 
    isNone:true,
    search: '',
   items: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Guava', 'Ape', 'Bands'],
    get searchResults () {
      let datalist= this.items.filter(
          i => i.startsWith(this.search)
      );
      isNone = datalist.length == 0;
      return datalist;
    }  
  }"
```

Again thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prefix each data property with `this.` in the component definition, so you have to use `this.isNone` in the getter method:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>


<div x-data="{isNone:true,
              search: '',
              items: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Guava', 'Ape', 'Bands'],
              get searchResults () {
                let datalist= this.items.filter(
                    i => i.startsWith(this.search)
                );
                this.isNone = datalist.length == 0;
                return datalist;
              }}">
  <input type="text" x-model="search" />
  <ul class="max-h-72 scroll-py-2 overflow-y-auto text-sm text-gray-800" id="options" role="listbox">
    <template x-for="(item, index) in searchResults">
      <li class="cursor-default select-none px-4 py-2" role="option" x-text="item" tabindex="-1"></li>
    </template>
  </ul>

  <div x-show="isNone">Not found</div>
</div>
```